# Android ant override location of res folder using build.properties

Tags: android, ant

So I am setting up my project to use ant to do automated builds but with one of the external libaries I have run into an issue. The external libary src and res folder point to another projects res and src folder (using LinkedResources in eclipse to do this). So the build fails when building this project because it cannot find the res folder. I made it find the src folder by overriding the source.dir in ant.properties to point to the path of the src folder. I tried to the same by using resource.dir but it does not work. Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the res location using the property resource.absolute.dir. The default value is res.